# How to create a Symmetric Key object with "Azuere.Security.KeyVaults.Keys" package .net 4.7 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I am upgrading azure packages of my existing .net 4.7 application. Earlier it used "**Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault**" which is deprecated now, So I updated the package to "**Azure.Security.KeyVault**".
My azure blob data is encrypted and the encryption key is stored in one of the secrets in the keyvault.
Using the Older package we created a Symmetric Key:

```
var blobencryptionkey = Some value from Key Vault Secret "aaaaaa";
SymmetricKey symmetricKey = new SymmetricKey("aaaaaa", Convert.FromBase64String(blobencryptionkey));
```

and then the same Symmetric key was used to create the BlobRequestOptions:

```
BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(symmetricKey, null);
BlobRequestOptions myBlobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions { EncryptionPolicy = policy };
// Then later the blob data was downloaded in the below format:
CloudBlockBlob blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream, null, myBlobRequestOptions, null).Wait();
```

The same functionality I want to achieve using the latest package, I figured out we can do this using CryptographyClient, so the implementaion I did for the same is (But this option uses Azure Key Vault key and for me I have to use Azure Key Vault Secret):

```
CryptographyClient cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(new Uri($@"https://xxxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/aaaaaa"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
//aaaaaa -> Secret ID name
KeyResolver keyResolver = new KeyResolver(new DefaultAzureCredential());
ClientSideEncryptionOptions encryptionOptions = new ClientSideEncryptionOptions(ClientSideEncryptionVersion.V2_0)
 {
   KeyEncryptionKey = cryptoClient,
   KeyResolver = keyResolver,
   KeyWrapAlgorithm = "RSA-OAEP"
};
BlobClientOptions options = new SpecializedBlobClientOptions() { ClientSideEncryption = encryptionOptions };
BlobServiceClient ServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(AzFac.ConnectionString, options);
foreach (BlobItem b in ServiceClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: DirectoryPath))
{
  BlobClient blob = ServiceClient.ContainerClient.GetBlobClient(b.Name);
  await blob.DownloadToAsync(DownloadPath);
}
```

But when I execute this code I get the following error:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
> at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
> at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
> at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography.KeyResolver.d__9.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

Cryptography client is for crypto, asymmetric keys.
You should use SecretClient for storing symmetric keys.